# Cannot resolve some domains with dnsmasq

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dnsmasq, networkmanager

My machine runs ArchLinux, with NetworkManager and dnsmasq. Dnsmasq should forward all requests to Google's DNS 8.8.8.8, and therefore should simply act as a local cache in front of Google's DNS.

For some odd reason, some domains like analytics.google.com do not resolve on my machine, but if I manually edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to specify 8.8.8.8 directly, they work.

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
# Configuration file for NetworkManager.
# See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf` (only the relevant part, everything else is commented):

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Try to issue the command ``dnsmasq --no-daemon --log-queries`` and see what is happening when you try to resolve those names

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar Thanks for the tip, I'll try that.

Comment: @user168317 Any luck so far? I think I have the same issue.

Comment: @rausch Unfortunately, no. I just ended up disabling dnsmasq...